# Функция для js отправка текста

Tags: javascript

есть функция которая обрабатывается через клик в textarea, как сделать такую же на на кнопку? `{{STORY_ID}}` - это id поста к которому привязан textarea , а `{{PUBLISHER_ID}}` - это id комментария. То есть как сделать чтобы кнопка отправляла это все?

```
onkeyup="postComment(this.value,{{STORY_ID}},{{PUBLISHER_ID}},event);">
```

Comment: onclick="postComment(this.value,{{STORY_ID}},{{PUBLISHER_ID}},event);">

Comment: Ой какое классное решение) Наверно я сам до этого додуматься не мог. Он что содержимое себя будет отправлять ?

Comment: вместо this.value $(this).closest('form').find('textarea[name=your_name]').val()